# GraphQL.ExecutionError: Deserialization can only be performed by Sitecore Administrators

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-cli

I am trying to install the Sitecore items package using the Sitecore CLI command line, I created a package using the same name as **SitecoreCliProject.itempackage** and now trying to install following this [Link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/create-and-install-a-sitecore-content-serialization-package.html)

I am trying yo install the package by using the command

```
sitecore ser pkg install -f sitecoreCliTest.itempackage --client-id <your client id> --client-secret <your client secret> --cm <your content management host> --auth <your identity host>
```

I can see below the error in PowerShell. And I am running PowerShell from Admin.

```
GraphQL.ExecutionError: Deserialization can only be performed by Sitecore Administrators.
```

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Did you configure your Identity Server and Content Management roles for non-interactive client login?

Comment: Yes, I already did that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turnout issue of config changes was not applied properly, I created a config named - `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.ClientCredentialsMapping.config` following https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/configure-a-non-interactive-client-login.html and changes were not showing in `showconfig.aspx` for this config, so I created the `zzz` folder under `App_Config/Include` folder and put this `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.ClientCredentialsMapping.config` under this folder and checked `showconfig.aspx`, this time I saw my config changes and ran the below command

```
sitecore ser pkg install -f sitecoreCliTest.itempackage --client-id <your client id> --client-secret <your client secret> --cm <your content management host> --auth <your identity host>
```

It worked successfully.

Comment: We do face the same issue and followed the same steps but did not get resolved. Any suggestions we should look for?